# Pass variable via ajax in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a button in `foreach` to give user projects,that when i click on button open popup to create Reports of work my code is here:

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->projects as $project)
   <a href="#">
      <button type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$project->id}}" id="Addtr">
        today Report
    </button>
   </a>
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    id="myModal{{$project->id}}">
      <input type="hidden" value="{{$project->id}}" id="project_id">
          <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="description">
               </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn bg-teal btn-block btn-lg 
                    AddTodayReport"
                   data-dismiss="modal"
                      id="AddTodayReport">save
              </button>
    </div>
     {{csrf_field()}}

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {                                                                   
     $('#AddTodayReport').click(function (event) {
        var project_id = $('#project_id').val();
        var description = $('#description').val();
          console.log(project_id);
   });
  });
 </script>
```

My problem is here that when i click on save button *(#AddTodayReport)* to pass data to ajax and print `project_id` in console i just give first project's id and in other project i don't give Anything,I print `{{project->id}}` before input and receive currently for any project, How can i solve my problem?

Comment: If for each iterated more than once, the id project_id is duplicated, so use different id dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change you id to class. Because ID must be unique. It cant be duplicate.

So change modal as below

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    id="myModal{{$project->id}}">
      <input type="hidden"  value="{{$project->id}}"  class="project_id">
          <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
            <input type="text"   class="form-control description" >
               </div>
            <button type="submit"  class="btn bg-teal btn-block btn-lg 
                    AddTodayReport"
                   data-dismiss="modal"
                      class="AddTodayReport">save
              </button>
    </div>
```

After changing  id to class add javascript as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {                                                                   
     $('.AddTodayReport').click(function (event) {
        var project_id = $(this).parent().children('.project_id').val();
        var description = $(this).parent().find('.description').val();
          console.log(project_id);
   });
  });
```

Comment: I don't Give anything in console